# Check Attachment is updated or not in parent model for Active storage attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, activemodel

I am migrating the attachments from paperclip to Active storage.

In paperclip, we can check whether the file is updated by using the active model dirty as below,

> **after_update_commit :notify_users, if: :saved_change_to_file_updated_at?**

But in Active storage, how can we check whether the file is updated, Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [attachment_changes](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model#attachment_changes-instance_method).
This method will return an object that specifies the changes made to each of your attachments.

```
after_update_commit do
  notify_users if attachment_changes['file'].present? # or maybe something more elaborate with some specific attribute
end
```